# Jooq with gradle using nu.studer plugin :: how to define matcher strategies inside build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jooq

I have an issue with defining matcher strategy when using nu.studer gradle plugin.

I have tried something like:

```
generator {
    strategy {
        matchers {
            tables {
                table {
                    pojoClass {
                        transform = 'PASCAL'
                                expression = '$0_POJO'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when I try to run a build I get an error:

Execution failed for task ':generateSampleJooqSchemaSource'.

> javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>    - with linked exception:
>   [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'matchers'. No child element is expected at this point.]

Keep in mind that when using .xml file to define matcher strategies like this:

```
<strategy>
  <matchers>
    <tables>
      <table>
        <pojoClass>
          <transform>PASCAL</transform>
          <expression>$0_POJO</expression>
        </pojoClass>
      </table>
    </tables>               
  </matchers>
</strategy>
```

everything is fine.

Could someone please help and explain what am I doing wrong? Is the syntax for defining matcher rules inside gradle build different from what I have tried? As I can not find any examples for that - nor documentation regarding this.

Thanks a lot.

Best Regards,
Marko

Comment: For the record, for future visitors, this was also recorded as a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/issues/28) and as a [jOOQ User Group E-Mail](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/jooq-user/CdzTFyWdY3M/gsEadEvICgAJ)

Answer (score 2):

When using matchers, the name needs to be explicitly set to null like this:

```
strategy {
    name = null
    matchers {
      tables {
        table {
            pojoClass {
                transform = 'PASCAL'
                expression = '\$0_POJO'
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This plugin consumes JAXB classes generated from this [XSD](https://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.9.0.xsd). The name on the Strategy element has a default value and that's an issue since is part of an XSD choice element, i.e. only one element can be present. This is the only choice element in the whole XSD, so this workaround only needs to be applied here.

This has been documented [here](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/blob/0b85914ab3ce5bc2ca0f8bed3c9728b9f33e7357/README.md#L197-L197) and an automated test has been provided [here](https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin/blob/0b85914ab3ce5bc2ca0f8bed3c9728b9f33e7357/src/test/groovy/nu/studer/gradle/jooq/JooqFuncTest.groovy#L114-L114).